# CsvHelper Map Colletion

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I'm mapping csv file with School records using [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)
The end result should be list of Schools.
[Similar issue can be found here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/csvhelper/wojFoDVkSd0)

```
 public class School
{
    public IList<Student> Students{ get; set; } 
}

public class Student
{
    public StudentRef Reference{ get; set; }
}

public class StudentRef
{
    public string RefNumber{ get; set; }
}
```

One of the columns found in the CSV file is **SRef** which should be linked to `StudentRef.RefNumber`

```
public sealed class StudentRefMap : CsvClassMap<StudentRef>
    {
        public StudentRefMap ()
        {

            Map(m => m.RefNumber).Name("SRef");
        }
    }

     public sealed class StudentMap : CsvClassMap<Student>
    {
        public StudentMap ()
        {

             References<StudentRefMap >(m => m.Reference);
        }
    }

    public sealed class SchoolMap : CsvClassMap<School>
    {
        public SchoolMap ()
        {

            //References<StudentMap>(m => m.Students);//doesn't work
             Map(m => m.Students)
                .ConvertUsing(row => new List<Student>
                {row.GetRecord<Student>()}); // doesn't work
        }
    }
```

I want to map csv file with list of `Schools`, however one columns is referring to `StudentRef` so using **CSVHelper**, how can i achieve that?

Comment: this is an unclear post. Have you given any thought to linq to csv ?

Comment: Ok, sorry my question isn't clear, i did modify it a bit hoping it's more clear now. also i have to use CsvHelper , thanks

Comment: I think you have to read the records manually because of the nested objects: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/#reading-reading-records-manually

Answer (score 2):

Use a `ReferenceMap`. http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/#mapping-reference-map

```
public sealed class PersonMap : CsvClassMap<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        Map( m => m.Id );
        Map( m => m.Name );
        References<AddressMap>( m => m.Address );
    }
}

public sealed class AddressMap : CsvClassMap<Address>
{
    public AddressMap()
    {
        Map( m => m.Street );
        Map( m => m.City );
        Map( m => m.State );
        Map( m => m.Zip );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Josho for answering my question.
ReferenceMap doesn't work. the example you give is not similar to mine
in my case: Person has List<Address> and each address has class city
now i have to map City.Name but the list of address is the issue
check your answer here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/csvhelper/wojFoDVkSd0

Comment: @Maro did you get any solution ?