# Using CSVHelper how to deserialise an CSV with a list of Sub Item

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

#### Question:

Given to object `FooBar` that contains a List of `Bar`, with `FooBar` and `Bar` define as such:

```
class FooBar{
    int FooID {get;set;}
    string FooProperty1 {get;set;}
    List<Bar> Bars {get;set;};
}

class Bar{
    int BarID {get;set;}    
    string BarProperty1 {get;set;}  
    string BarProperty2 {get;set;}  
    string BarProperty3 {get;set;}
}
```

I get the following CSV as input:

```
1,FooProperty1,BarID_1,BarProperty1_1,BarProperty2_1,BarProperty3_1,BarID_2,BarProperty1_2,BarProperty2_2,BarProperty3_2
```

Where the field BarID, BarProperty1, BarProperty2, BarProperty3 are suffixed by their indice in the collection.

How do I deserialise this input into my object?

[image]

---

#### input Exemple:

1 instance of FooBar, and 2 sub Bar:   `1,FooProperty1,BarID_1,BarProperty1_1,BarProperty2_1,BarProperty3_1,BarID_2,BarProperty1_2,BarProperty2_2,BarProperty3_2`

1 instance of FooBar but no Bar:
`1,FooProperty1`

---

#### Tries:

I have try using Convert in order to map those property to a new instance of Bar like :

```
public class FooBarMap : ClassMap<FooBar> 
{
    public FooBarMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.FooID);
        Map(m => m.Bars).ConvertUsing(row =>
        {            
            var list = new List<Bar>
            {
                new Bar { 
                    BarProperty1 = row.GetField("BarProperty1_1"), 
                    BarProperty2 = row.GetField("BarProperty2_1"),
                    // .. Other Properties
                },
                new Bar {}, //.. Same on _2
            };
            return list;
        });
    }
}
```

Of course no control over the input. I would have been sending Json/Xml not CSV.

Comment: Sorry for the Json.et instead of CSV Helper and the wrong tag. it must be friday.

Comment: Wouldn't the bar properties be better as an array in your C# model, rather than individual properties? It seems like they are all related items of the same type

Comment: @Fubo, Just a typo from the simplification. Don't mind it . I will edit asap.

Comment: @ADyson, Ho they are name, cust, org, I just renamed them into [ClassName]Propertiy[Number]. It's not a Dict or an array of string. They are not all string just string is easier for a MCVE

Comment: But properties names are not dynamic. I know them (20+) and The pattern will alway be "[KnowPropertyName]_[Index+1]".

Comment: Don't you need to pass the constructor a string? public FooBarMap(string inputLine)

Comment: @jdweng, No. ClassMap is only there to tell the Mapping to the `CsvReader` like in this [exemple](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/mapping-by-index/).

Comment: According to the [docs](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/api/CsvHelper.Configuration/ClassMap/) you can map a member to another class map via the `References` method

Comment: @LennartStoop,  I was reading the Exemple part of the doc [here](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/). And the test on GitHub but I can have miss it. Will check into it to see if it can help. But from this doc alone, i fail to see how. Will investigate

Comment: Make custom type : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42133413/csvhelper-set-default-custom-typeconverter

Comment: @LennartStoop, Reference look promising i was looking at https://stackoverflow.com/a/36783742/9260725 but there we have simple mapping. But mine will either use index or column name makeing me specify what index for what element of the list

Comment: ok,@jdweng, im looking into it. sorry for delay jumping from doc to doc got lost trying things. While i see how this custom convert will work for mapping bool to a enum or things like that. I fail to see how to make it group column based on index or name. Will read the answer till Something click

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its possible with a **custom type converter** but tricky.

You need to decorate the property with an `Index` attribute (even though it's not used)

```
public class FooBar
{
    [Index(2)]
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

The converter is used for both reading and writing, so you need to override two methods:

```
  public class BarListConverter : DefaultTypeConverter
  {
    public override object ConvertFromString(string text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
      var list = new List<Bar>();
      if (text == null) return list;
      do
      {
        var barIndex = list.Count + 1;
        var bar = new Bar
        {
          BarID = row.GetField<int>($"BarID_{barIndex}"),
          BarProperty1 = row.GetField<string>($"BarProperty1_{barIndex}"),
          BarProperty2 = row.GetField<string>($"BarProperty2_{barIndex}"),
          BarProperty3 = row.GetField<string>($"BarProperty3_{barIndex}")
        };
        list.Add(bar);
      } while (row.Context.CurrentIndex > 0 && row.Context.CurrentIndex < row.Context.Record.Length - 1);
      return list;
    }

    public override string ConvertToString(object value, IWriterRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
      var bars = value as List<Bar>;
      if (bars == null) return null;
      foreach (var bar in bars)
      {
        row.WriteField(bar.BarID);
        row.WriteField(bar.BarProperty1);
        row.WriteField(bar.BarProperty2);
        row.WriteField(bar.BarProperty3);
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Reading:

```
  public List<FooBar> Reading()
  {
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
    {
      writer.WriteLine(
        "FooID,FooProperty1,BarID_1,BarProperty1_1,BarProperty2_1,BarProperty3_1,BarID_2,BarProperty1_2,BarProperty2_2,BarProperty3_2");
      writer.WriteLine("1,Foo1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8");
      writer.Flush();
      stream.Position = 0;

      csv.Configuration.HeaderValidated = null;
      csv.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;
      csv.Configuration.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<List<Bar>>(new BarListConverter());

      return csv.GetRecords<FooBar>().ToList();
    }
  }
```

Writing:

```
  public string Writing(List<FooBar> data)
  {
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
    {
      csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
      csv.Configuration.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<List<Bar>>(new BarListConverter());
      csv.WriteRecords(data);
      writer.Flush();
      stream.Position = 0;

      return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Comment: It's somehow a classic problem, that had no easy to find solution. I hope the Bounty will give this answer more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a very simplified method that will iterate over the key/value pairs...

```
private static FooBar Parse(string value)
{
    // a basic check for null or empty string
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));

    // split the string
    string[] split = value.Split(',');

    // a basic check for properly formed key/value pairs in the string
    if (split.Length < 2 || split.Length % 2 != 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Malformed string.", nameof(value));

    // put the values into our object
    var result = new FooBar();

    // Foo pair
    result.FooID = Int32.Parse(split[0]);
    result.FooProperty1 = split[1];

    // Bar pairs
    result.Bars = new List<Bar>();
    for (int i = 2; i < split.Length; i = i + 4)
    {
        result.Bars.Add(new Bar()
        {
            BarID = split[i],
            BarProperty1 = split[i+1],
            BarProperty2 = split[i+2],
            BarProperty3 = split[i+3]
        });
    }

    return result;
}
```

I ran this against the two examples like so

```
string value = "1,FooProperty1";
FooBar result = Parse(value); // works
```

and

```
string value = "1,FooProperty1,BarID_1,BarProperty1_1,BarProperty2_1,BarProperty3_1,BarID_2,BarProperty1_2,BarProperty2_2,BarProperty3_2";
FooBar result = Parse(value); // works
```

note that your class needs to be slightly updated to

```
public class FooBar
{
    public int FooID { get; set; }
    public string FooProperty1 { get; set; }
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string BarID { get; set; } // you originally had this as int
    public string BarProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string BarProperty2 { get; set; }
    public string BarProperty3 { get; set; }
}
```

To me, this option seems far less convoluted and, easier to read overall. I don't particularly see any reason that you have to force the conversion to be done via other means such as using the CSVHelper class.

Comment: The Csv in my exemple is clean and simplify. But it's a real Csv from a real Customer. that means Csv helper is a must have for the parsing. Multilines data, Escaped column separator (eg: `"foo;";"foo,bar"`). But the simplification will be good for people without those constraints, those able to simply split.