# Write an object with a List<T> field to CSV

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I'm learning C# and object serialization. I need to save an object in a .csv file. I tried [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) but couldn't find the answer to my question.

Suppose I have an object like this:

```
public class Record
{
    ...
    public List<string> Collection { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

How do I use [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) to store the values of *Collection* in a .csv file along with other primitive types in a record of csv file?

Comment: When you followed the tutorial for CSVHelper, what happened?
https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started#writing-a-csv-file

Comment: CSV is a flat file format; it doesn't support embedded types unless you work out some sort of custom scheme.  Writing CSV files is very easy; why don't you just write some code to do it?

Comment: You said you "tried CsvHelper" but I see no evidence of that in your post. If you tried it and failed, then provide a [MCVE] and explain how it didn't work.

Comment: Storing data to a CSV is not serialization.  Most serializers should be able to store such things  easily

Comment: If your object contains a list and some primitives, what would you want the output to look like?

Comment: @StephenByrne All other fileds (primitive types) were visible and correctly stored, Collection field was seemingly ignored.

Comment: how about `csv.WriteRecords(myRecord.Collection);` ?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not to start a big debate, but I didn't wanna leave your statement completely unchallenged, for Anton's benefit. Writing a CSV may *sound* easy, but it's deceptively tricky with the need to escape commas and inner quotes etc. Don't try to reinvent the wheel and create your own CSV writer - stick to existing libraries that handle the nuances for you.

Comment: is the content of `Collection` the only column that you want to have in your csv?

Comment: Escaping quotes: `string.Replace("\"", "\"\"")`. Presumably one does something similar for commas.

Comment: "How?" Is exactly the right question. In a [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), how do you represent a nested object? Or a collection? This is not about tool like CSV Helper. It's about definition

Comment: @RobertHarvey Great, you handled double quotes. Now you've gotta do that for single quotes. And now you've gotta escape commas. It adds up. Before you know it, you've written a library that hasn't been nearly as battle-tested as CsvHelper.

Comment: Regardless, the problem is not producing output; the problem is defining what that output is supposed to look like.  CSVHelpers will not provide any assistance in that regard.

Comment: @AntonIugov - can we just clarify something. Do you really need to save this as CSV? CSV is a flat format, it's not really designed to store nested information. Perhaps if you updated the question to explain what exactly you need - and how you think it should look - we could better help you :)

Comment: Note thats it's not impossible ? but you still have to define exactlly how you want to handle it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55745715/using-csvhelper-how-to-deserialise-an-csv-with-a-list-of-sub-item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collections are ignored by `CsvHelper` by default. However, using a `ClassMap` you can use `Index` to indicate you want a simple collection of string to be output with the other properties. (Not well documented.)

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var records = new List<Record>
        {
            new Record { Id = 1, Name = "Record1", Collection = new List<string>{"First", "Second", "Third"}},
            new Record { Id = 2, Name = "Record2", Collection = new List<string>{"First", "Second"}},
        };

        using (var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out))
        {
            csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<RecordMap>();

            csv.WriteRecords(records);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}

public class RecordMap : ClassMap<Record>
{
    public RecordMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id);
        Map(m => m.Name);
        Map(m => m.Collection).Index(3);
    }
}

public class Record
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Collection { get; set; }
}
```

Outputs:

```
1,Record1,First,Second,Third
2,Record2,First,Second
```

If you know the max number of items in the Collection, you can also set an end index and have `CsvHelper` create the headings for each collection item.

```cs
public class RecordMap : ClassMap<Record>
{
    public RecordMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id);
        Map(m => m.Name);
        Map(m => m.Collection).Index(3, 5);
    }
}
```

Remove `csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;` and now it will also print the header record for you.
Outputs:

```
Id,Name,Collection1,Collection2,Collection3
1,Record1,First,Second,Third
2,Record2,First,Second
```

Comment: in the example above, list data outputed  as new columns, is it possible to write them in new line ( in rows, with/without ) duplication of other common columns for example :     1, Record1,First   /n   1, Record1, Second /n 1, Record1, Third /n  2, Record2, Frirst /n  2, Record2, Second ?

Comment: @Vitalii You can, but you would have to write it manually.  `foreach (var record in records){ foreach (var item in record.Collection){ csv.WriteRecord(record); csv.WriteField(item); csv.NextRecord(); }}` Also remove the `RegisterClassMap<RecordMap>()`