# Using CsvHelper to iterate child objects into CSV file - Property 'Int32' is not defined for type

Tags: c#, csvhelper

Using [CSV Helper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)

I'm trying to output the contents of a collection each of which contains child collections.
I've successfully used CSV helper on single ienumerable collections before, however I'm stuck when it comes to including child objects.

As below:

Method to write out the CSV

```
public void DumpData(List<FzLogModelSessionChronological> logData)
    {
        var fileName = $@"csv-{DateTime.Now:yy-MM-dd hhmmss}.csv";

        try
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter($@"{_csvLocation}\{fileName}", true))
            {
                using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                {
                    csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<SessionMap>();
                    csv.WriteRecords(logData);
                   
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           
        }
        finally
        {
           
        }
```

Mapping Classes

```
public sealed class SessionMap : ClassMap<FzLogModelSessionChronological>
{
    public SessionMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.SessionId);
        References<SesssionDataMap>(m => m.SessionData);
    }
}

public sealed class SesssionDataMap : ClassMap<FzLogModel>
{
    public SesssionDataMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.SessionId);
        Map(m => m.CommandString);
        Map(m => m.Command);
        Map(m => m.SourceIp);
        Map(m => m.User);
        Map(m => m.ActionDateTime);
    }
}
```

The CSV is created, the header rows are also created but it generates error on the first

> Property 'Int32 SessionId' is not defined for type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FileZillaFtpLogParser.Models.FzLogModel]'

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Csv is not very good for creating lists of lists.  If `SessionData` was `FzLogModel` instead of `List<FzLogModel>` then your code would work just fine. I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55748053/2355006) that might work for you that I converted to work with the latest version of `CsvHelper`.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var logData = new List<FzLogModelSessionChronological>(){
        new FzLogModelSessionChronological{
            SessionId = 1,
            SessionData = new List<FzLogModel>(){
                new FzLogModel {
                    SessionId = 1,
                    CommandString = "CommandString1",
                    Command = "Command1"
                },
                new FzLogModel {
                    SessionId = 2,
                    CommandString = "CommandString2",
                    Command = "Command2"
                }
            }
        }
    };

    try
    {
        var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture){ HasHeaderRecord = false};
        using (var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, config))
        {
            csv.Context.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<List<FzLogModel>>(new FzLogModelConverter());
            csv.WriteRecords(logData);
           
        }            
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       ex.Dump();
    }
    finally
    {
       
    }
}

public class FzLogModelSessionChronological
{
    public int SessionId { get; set; }
    [Index(2)]
    public List<FzLogModel> SessionData { get; set; }
}

public class FzLogModel
{
    public int SessionId { get; set; }
    public string CommandString { get; set; }
    public string Command { get; set; }
}

public class FzLogModelConverter : DefaultTypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFromString(string text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        var list = new List<FzLogModel>();
        if (text == null) return list;
        do
        {
            var barIndex = list.Count + 1;
            var bar = new FzLogModel
            {
                SessionId = row.GetField<int>($"SessionId_{barIndex}"),
                CommandString = row.GetField<string>($"CommandString_{barIndex}"),
                Command = row.GetField<string>($"Command_{barIndex}")
            };
            list.Add(bar);
        } while (row.CurrentIndex > 0 && row.CurrentIndex < row.Parser.Record.Length - 1);
        return list;
    }

    public override string ConvertToString(object value, IWriterRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        var bars = value as List<FzLogModel>;
        if (bars == null) return null;
        foreach (var bar in bars)
        {
            row.WriteField(bar.SessionId);
            row.WriteField(bar.CommandString);
            row.WriteField(bar.Command);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```